# recursion over tuples list in haskell

Tags: haskell

Is there a recursion way to do somethings like below?

```
    updateOs2 :: [(Rotor, Int)] -> [(Rotor, Int)]
    updateOs2 [(a,x),(b,y),(c,z)]
        | x == 25 && y == 25 && z == 25 = [(a,0),(b,0),(c,0)]
        | x == 25 && y == 25            = [(a,0),(b,0),(c,z+1)]
        | x == 25                       = [(a,0),(b,y+1),(c,z)]
        | otherwise                     = [(a,x+1),(b,y),(c,z)]
```

I have tried to do recursion, but quite confused. Because once the last element `z` is passed the list comes to empty, can not go back to `x` anymore.

Comment: Are you planning on having lists with more than three `(Rotor, Int)` pairs? If not, there's nothing to gain by using recursion (which is what you would use to process lists of arbitrary length).

Comment: @chepner yeah, just three pairs

Comment: You are doing different things to each tuple so it does not really make sense to use recursion. If you were applying the same operations to each tuple then it would be useful.

Comment: You should use a type that represents exactly 3 such pairs, then; e.g. `data Foo = Foo (Rotor, Int) (Rotor, Int) (Rotor, Int)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work

```
updateOs2 [] = []
updateOs2 ((a,x):xs)
    | x == 25 = (a,0): (updateOs2 xs)
    | otherwise =  (a,x+1):xs
```

Comment: This is not quite equivalent (though it's not clear if the OP is *looking* for something equivalent). This will update, say, `(b, 23)` to `(b, 24)` even if `a != 25`.

Comment: @chepner if `a != 25`, `(a,x+1)` is appended to rest of list without any recursive call hence `(b,23)` won't be updated to `(b,24)`. I tested it in ghci and it works as expected

Comment: Sorry, yes.I  Corrected it. I used different name in ghci and made mistake while copying.

Comment: this nested rucursion really enlighten me! Thanks a lot